# Add d3-tip infobox to d3.js SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Would like to add an infobox to a `d3.js` file.

Have studied [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461512/add-a-link-to-another-page-with-d3-js), and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569225/d3-js-click-to-link-to-another-url-encoded-with-variables), and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790124/modify-lines-tooltip-on-hover), and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41ejgkqp/).

Most of the following `HTML` + `JavaScrip` + `d3.js` + `JSON` file works as planned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .node { cursor: pointer; }
  .node circle { fill: #fff; stroke: steelblue; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
  .node text { font: 10px sans-serif; }
  .link { fill: none; stroke: #ccc; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
  .link:hover { stroke:blue; }
  div#tooltip{ color:#ffffff; background:#000000; opacity:1; padding:5px; }
</style>
<title>Soils with Local JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Soils with Local JSON</h1>
<div id="tooltip" style="display:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
},
width = 1000 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
});

//Add tool tip: d3-tip.
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .html(function(d) { return '<a href="' + d.url + '">' + d.name + '</a>' });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

//Call tool-tip in var svg =
    .call(tip);

var root = {
"name":"Soil","children":[
{"name":"Albaqualfs","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albaqualfs","children":[
{"name":"Aeric Albaqualfs","children":[
{"name":"Auxvasse"},
{"name":"Cayagua"},
{"name":"Mamou"},
{"name":"Marine"},
{"name":"Medoc"},
{"name":"Springfield"},
{"name":"Tenot"}]}]}]};

root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            var r = d3.select(this).node().getBoundingClientRect();
            d3.select("div#tooltip")
                .style("display", "inline")
                .style("top", (r.top-25) + "px")
                .style("left", r.left + "px")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .text(d.test);
        })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        d3.select("div#tooltip").style("display", "none")
    });

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now would like to add an infobox for an item that displays information like this:
[image: infobox layour]

Am currently working with `d3-tip`.

The included file has a JSON field for "name" and "url". It also includes an attempt to map the "url" to `d.url` and "name" to `d.name`.

One issue is the need to keep the infobox temporarily persistent so that users can click the item's `URL` if they choose. Once the cursor is moved away from the infobox, it should clear.

The target infobox image above shows an `X` to close the infobox if clicked. However, I don't see how to introduce a second selector - the current selector opens the next level of the tree. Therefore, I'm hoping that a temporarily persistent infobox, revealed on mouseover, can be implemented.

The infobox can overlay the tree data - no need to re-draw the tree to adjust to the placement of the infobox.

**How to correct the d3-tip code to work as desired?**

If an **SO** reader uses an alternative to `d3-tip` that basically accomplishes the same task, that would be good too.